# Returning 2 values of different type from one class to another and update GUI

Tags: c#, return

Now I am struggling with returning 2 values of different type from one of my helper classes to my main class with my form.

So I am passing to my method path to the xls file. Then I am loading values from that xls file to 2D array. After each row is loaded I am updating variable percent. This variable is telling me the percentage of loading process. Now I want to return this value to my main class so I can update one of my Labels.

After the loading process is completed I am returning the loaded array. So how can I update the label when returning 2D array?

This is my helper class and its method:

```
 class LoadReflexTime
{

     Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
     Form1 frm = new Form1();
     Label percenta;
     int percent;

     string[,] reflexTime1;

     public string[,] reflexTime(string cesta )
     {
        // LOAD XLS to ARRAY
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(cesta);
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

        int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

        reflexTime1 = new string[rowCount, colCount];
        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {
                string str = xlRange.Cells[i, j].Text;
                reflexTime1[i - 1, j - 1] = str;
            }

            percent = ((100 * i) / rowCount);
            // UPDATE LABEL (worked in my main class)
            percenta.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => percenta.Text = percent.ToString()+"%"));
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Súbor načítaný");

     return reflexTime1;


    }
```

Comment: What is your desired text in the label, can you give an example

Comment: I want to show the variable percent in my Label after each iteration. Example: 0 , 1, 2 , 3 ...., 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new class to wrap the two variables you want to return:

```
public class ReturnValue
{
    public string[,] Array { get; set; }
    public double Percent { get; set; }
}
```

You can then redefine your method to return that type:

```
public ReturnValue reflexTime(string cesta )
{
    ReturnValue output = new ReturnValue();

    // LOAD XLS to ARRAY
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(cesta);
    Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
    Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

    int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
    int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

    output.Array = new string[rowCount, colCount];
    for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
        {
            string str = xlRange.Cells[i, j].Text;
            output.Array[i - 1, j - 1] = str;
        }

        output.Percent = ((100 * i) / rowCount);
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Súbor načítaný");

    return output;

}
```

And then both values are available at the same time.

Comment: WindowsFormsApplication1.LoadReflexTime.reflexTime(string)': not all code paths return a value ... I am getting this error when I changed my code this way. Can you suggest something please?

Comment: you need to change the body of the method too. See my update.